# Openshift (Origin) Enable Images to Run with ROOT user

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, openshift, minishift

I am trying to run simple elk container with openshift(using minishift). The image I am trying to run is [this elk](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/) image. During image deploy to openshift it gives the following warning:

> Image sebp/elk runs as the root user which might not be permitted by your cluster administrator.

I Ignore this error and create deployment with this image. After that pod tries to start container but it fails with following error:

> Starting periodic command scheduler cron
>
> cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied ...fail!
>
> chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/elasticsearch': Operation not permitted

I thought it i related with root user warning and then tried these steps [Enable Images to Run with USER in the Dockerfile](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-dockerhub-images-that-require-root) and [Grant a Service Account Access to the Privileged SCC](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#grant-a-service-account-access-to-the-privileged-scc)
 . Both of them failed with following errors:

> Murats-MacBook-Pro-2:~ murat$ oc adm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated
>
> Error from server (Forbidden):User "system" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope
>
> Murats-MacBook-Pro-2:~ murat$ oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid system:serviceaccount:elk:elk
>
> Error from server (Forbidden): User "system" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are likely not an admin user. I can't remember if Minishift enables sudoer role, if it does, try passing the ``--as system:admin`` to the commands. Otherwise just try ``oc login -u system:admin`` as it may set up access so you can switch to admin user that way.

Comment: oc login -u system:admin worked. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I will approve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands to enable running an image as `anyuid` need to be run as an admin. For Minishift you can login as admin using:

```
oc login -u system:admin
```

Remember to login back as your normal user when done.

Answer (score 5):

We have [`anyuid` addon](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/blob/master/addons/anyuid/anyuid.addon) for this specific use case. Consider using it.

To use it, run following command

```
minishift addon apply anyuid
```

To know more about addon, check here [Minishift Addons](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/using/addons.html).